# How do I see changes made to a kernel module?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, insmod

I have a module running on my Linux machine and can see it using lsmod command. Now I made some changes (added some printk) to this module, recompiled it and got the .ko.

Now I did *rmmod* to remove this module (some other modules also which are using this module), did *insmod xxx.ko* and rebooted the system.

Now where do I see the statements added using printk? I tried to see using

```
dmesg grep | "SPI RW"
```

But I couldn't find anything. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You don't need to reboot.  Just reload the module.  If you reboot, the module will be reloaded from the installed module rather than your modified one.  To put your module where it will be loaded at boot time (not recommended until you know it won't crash your system), run `make modules_install`

Answer (score 3):

Try `vim /var/log/messages` or open messages in a text editor to verify.

For enabling */var/log/messages*, edit file */etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf*

Change the following paragraph:

```
...
#
# Some "catch-all" log files.
#
#*.=debug;\
#       auth,authpriv.none;\
#       news.none;mail.none     -/var/log/debug
#*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
#       auth,authpriv.none;\
#       cron,daemon.none;\
#       mail,news.none          -/var/log/messages
....
```

to the following:

...

```
#
# Some "catch-all" log files.
#
*.=debug;\
        auth,authpriv.none;\
        news.none;mail.none     -/var/log/debug
*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
        auth,authpriv.none;\
        cron,daemon.none;\
        mail,news.none          -/var/log/messages
...
```

and do `restart rsyslog`.

Comment: on my file system there is nothing like /var/log/messages

Comment: open `vi /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`                                    ...
#
# Some "catch-all" log files.
#
#*.=debug;\
#       auth,authpriv.none;\
#       news.none;mail.none     -/var/log/debug
#*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
#       auth,authpriv.none;\
#       cron,daemon.none;\
#       mail,news.none          -/var/log/messages
....

Comment: When I go and see my /etc Directory,Could only find syslog-startup.conf file .

Comment: inside `/etc/rsyslog.d/`

Comment: I run the command syslog.d and can see messages file in /var/log ,Now If I restart my system will /var/log/messages capture the log??

Comment: Try `tail -f /var/log/messages` look printing your module logs...then it will works

Comment: I did "tail -f /var/log/messages" after reboot but again nothing